# EOS STUDIO TERMINAL compilation issue

Tags: cleos, eosio-code, eos-studio

In terminal, I created a wallet, then created the eosio keys, imported that into the wallet, created an account with those keys, and set up my smart contract that has no errors, but when I try to do the compilation using this command

"eosio-cpp -abigen -o "

I get the error "Error while processing /Users/tagi/eos-contracts/src/helloworld.cpp.

abigen error".

When I try to deploy my smart contract in EOS studio I get this error:
"Unknown action setcode in contract eosio"

Also, I can't create a new account in EOS studio either because I get this error:
"Unknown action newaccount in contract eosio"

I'm still new to EOS studios and this has been a problem I can't seem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to ask this question on the eos studio telegram channel
https://t.me/eosstudioide

or on the eos developers telegram channel
https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1